# Crystal report 2008 formula

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

> Hi ,

I am new to crystal report. I have a problem to create formula :

Let's say :

I have two tables :

### tbl_Details :

**Emp_id**     **Emp_nameEmp_Deptt** 
 
1            Ram              MMM   
 
2            Naresh           NNN   
 
3            kapil            HHH   
 
4            Namita           DDD

### tbl_Mapping :

**Type1**    **Type2**    **Emp_Deptt** 
 
ButterSotch ButterScotch    NNN       
 
ButterScotch    Strawberry  DDD       
 
Olive       Starch      MMM       
 
Olive       Olive       HHH

### Note :  In the above tables, Emp_Deptt column is same.

> Now i want to create a formula like as below :

if Mapping.Type1 = Mapping.Type2 then find Emp_Deptt in Details table and get the Emp_name.
for example : 
Butterscotch = Butterscotch then Emp_Deptt is NNN matched with Details table and the Emp_name is Naresh.

if doesn't find any match then nothing to do.

Now, i want to create a formula to get the desired value and print place somewhere in crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

From Database Menu select 'Database Expert'. Add tbl_Mapping & tbl_Details to the selected tables.. make sure tbl_Mapping & tbl_Details are linked with Emp_Deptt fields.

Write following in the formula editor:
if {tbl_Mapping.Type1} = {tbl_Mapping.Type2} then {tbl_Details.Emp_name}